# Web API and gRPC in the same service

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc

I am trying to build a service that will host both Web API and gRPC endpoints.

Running the service locally and in Azure App Services, the Web API port must stay operating on the default kestrel port of 5000 with gRPC running on a different port.

As soon as gRPC is added, the default port 5000 throws an error 403 even though gRPC is responding on a different and the client is using required host.

```
    public static void BootstrapGrpc(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            var http2 = options.Limits.Http2;
            http2.InitialConnectionWindowSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2 MB
            http2.InitialStreamWindowSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB
         
#if DEBUG
            options.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
            {
                
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1;
                listenOptions.UseHttps();
            });
#endif
            
            options.ListenAnyIP(8080);
            options.ListenAnyIP(8585, listenOptions => 
            { 
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
            });
        });

        builder.Services.AddCodeFirstGrpc();
        
        _isGrpcBootstrapped = true;
    }
```

[image]